# facing issue in Lightning App builder Review

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

**Component Name:**  Some Issues Found

Use the label attribute of the  tag to provide an admin-friendly name for the component similar to the standard components.

Any body know about this issue ? and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the label attribute in the design file for your component it will show in the Lightning App Builder. Like:

```
<design:component label="My Label">

</design:component>
```

You can read about design files here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder.htm

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like one of the components you are using doesn't have the label="[Provide Label Here]" attribute filled out.

Necessary for accessibility.

It should probably also tell you which component (probably an input), that would be nice.